# Adding image with animation when scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to ask if this is possible and if you can show me how. Here's my thing:
I have a div for the logo3.png(big version) and a sticky navigation bar right-part-under.

http://jsfiddle.net/34Qw5/

```
<div id="logo_container">
<center><img src="images/Logo3.png" alt="My Company"/></center>
</div>
<div id="header_navi">
    <table width="50%" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td><a href="#"><img class="home_navi" data-alt-src="images/home_over.png" src="images/home.png" /></a></td>
        <td><a href="#"><img class="portfolio_navi" data-alt-src="images/portfolio_over.png" src="images/portfolio.png" /></a></td>
        <td><a href="#"><img class="quote_navi" data-alt-src="images/get_a_quote_over.png" src="images/get_a_quote.png" /></a></td>
        <td><a href="#"><img class="careers_navi" data-alt-src="images/careers_over.png" src="images/careers.png" /></a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

When I scroll down and the navigation bar reaches the top it will be sticked on the top and the big logo will be hidden which is working fine. Now, what I want to do is when the navigation bar reaches the top, I want my small version of my logo (logo_small.png) to be added on the left beside the navigation-bar. Help, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is jquery very basics... how come you can make the menu sticky but can't display an image ? your dev is on holidays ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see you're using [Sticky Plugin](http://stickyjs.com/) but there is no callback in there and you probably don't want to mess around with it. I suggest you drop the plugin and create your own sticky with just jQuery.

If your only looking to sticky your navigation bar with some top spacing (similar to this option `.sticky({topSpacing:10});`) and to show/hide the small logo , I think this will do:

```
var nav = $('#nav');
var smallLogo = $('#logo-small');
var navPos = nav.offset().top;
var topSpacing = 10;

$(document).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(scrollTop >=  navPos){
        nav.css({'position':'fixed','top':topSpacing});
        smallLogo.fadeIn(500);
    }else {
        nav.css({'position':'static'});
        smallLogo.fadeOut(500);
    }
});
```

You can check out this fiddle as well. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/34Qw5/3/)